# basic ES query using elasticutils

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

need help in formulating a basic elasticutils search query

I am trying to test elasticutils mainly becz I was not able to get optimum performance for #searches results / second. ( more details : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079117/elastic-search-performance-using-pyes) )

So far here is what I have done.

```
es=get_es(hosts=['localhost:9200'],timeout=30,default_indexes=['ncbi_taxa_names'],dump_curl=CurlDumper())


es.get_indices()
# [2012-08-22T15:36:10.639102]
curl -XGET
 http://localhost:9200/ncbi_taxa_names/_status
Out[26]: {u'ncbi_taxa_names': {'num_docs': 1316005}}

S().indexes('ncbi_taxa_names').values_dict()
Out[27]: [{u'tax_name': u'Conyza sp.', u'tax_id': u'41553'}, ...
```

so what I want to do is formulate a query where I can search for { "taxa_name":"cellvibrio"} and then do some comparison to how many search results I can retrieve with elasticutils compared to pyes.

May be it has something to do with the way the ES is running locally and not with the API's.

**Update1**

I tried the following and the searh results are still very similar to what I am getting from pyes. Now I am beginning to wonder whether it has something to do with how the local ES is running . Still need help figuring that out.

```
es=get_es(hosts=['localhost:9200'],timeout=30,default_indexes=['ncbi_taxa_names'],dump_curl=CurlDumper())


es.get_indices()
# [2012-08-22T15:36:10.639102]
curl -XGET
 http://localhost:9200/ncbi_taxa_names/_status
Out[26]: {u'ncbi_taxa_names': {'num_docs': 1316005}}

s=S().indexes('ncbi_taxa_names').values_dict()
Out[27]: [{u'tax_name': u'Conyza sp.', u'tax_id': u'41553'}, ...

results = s.query(tax_name='aurantiacus')  # using elasticutils
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: I could not tag the question with "elasticutils"  as there is no such category and my score doesn't allow me to create one